# How to install vue.js in my ubuntu system. | E: Unable to locate package vue |

Tags: vue.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am using ubuntu 18. I tried to install the vuejs. I have already installed node version 8.10 and npm version 3.5.2. while i tried to install i receiving error like this. I have attached the screen shot. [image]

Kindly refer below screen shot also

[image]

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install Vue in the global node_modules directory. 
A tried and true way is running the same command from within your node.js project.

1. `cd /home/hp/coolproject`
2. `npm install vue`

Another great way to use Vue is [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Okay. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install @vue/cli and possible options for you will be to either use `yarn` or `npm` but not `apt`. You will have to install the vue package globally so for that in `npm` use `-g` or `global` in `yarn`. The full commands will look like this:
`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` or `sudo yarn global add @vue/cli`. 
To make sure you have vue installed then run `vue --version` for short. 
Let me know is that fixes your problem.

Comment: will try and let you know